# Unable to create DataFrame for RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I'm trying to create a Dataframe with dynamic schema generation. Here's the code snippet:

```
def mapMetricList(row: Row): Seq[Metric] = ???

val fields = Seq("Field1", "Field2")

case class Metric(name: String, count: Long)
def convertMetricList(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val outputFields = df.schema.fieldNames.filter(f => fields.contains(f))

  val rdd = df.rdd.map(row => {
    val schema = row.schema
    val metrics = mapMetricList(row)
    val s = outputFields.map(name => row.get(schema.fieldIndex(name)))
    Row.fromSeq(s ++ Seq(metrics))
  })

  val nonMetricsSchema = outputFields.map( f => df.schema.apply(f))
  val metricField = StructField("total",ArrayType(ScalaReflection.schemaFor[Metric].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]),nullable=true)
  val schema = StructType(nonMetricsSchema ++ Seq(metricField))
  schema.printTreeString()
  val dff = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
  dff
}
```

However I keep getting these exceptions during runtime:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Metric is not a valid external type for schema of struct<name:string,count:bigint>
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.evalIfCondExpr3$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.evalIfFalseExpr4$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:290)
```

I'm using Spark 2.1.0

Comment: Such error may occur if class "Metric" is internal. Move class "Metric" to own file.

Comment: I have tried to move case class to a separate file but the error's still there.

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine with Spark 1.6 on my computer, I printed result of "convertMetricList" function. 
Maybe issue in "metricField" field "count" type. In your trace "bigint" mentioned, on my env type is "LongType":

```
StructField(total,ArrayType(
    StructType(StructField(name,StringType,true), 
    StructField(count,LongType,false)
),true),true)
```

You can check "metricField" types on yours env. If different, workaround is to hardcode Metric structure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tested my code on Spark 1.6 and it works. I don't know what changed in 2.0 that makes it stop working.

Comment: Apparently this was accidentally implemented in 1.6 and was removed from 2.0.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15507

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any solution or work around to fix these problems